# How to make all objects rotate in the same way

Tags: objects

In other words how do i prevent this from happening:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your pivot point is set to "Individual Origins". Switch it to "Median Point" if you want your objects to rotate around the selection center (as by default). Or you may also use any other pivot, like 3D cursor, etc.

[image: Pivot Point Selection]

[image: Rotation Origin]